# Turtlebot- 2012-01.10.iso problem with istallation use USB drive in the netbook of Turtlebot robot

Tags: usb, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I try to connect the netbook with Turtlebot and i following the istruction shown in the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Robot%20Setup.
In the netbook i have upgrade the version of ROS from diamonblack to electric, following the setup http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/electric/Robot%20Upgrade.Then i restart the Netbook.
Now i following the istructions for Obtaining the TurtleBot USB Drive i download the turtlebot-2012-01-10.iso but not working the procedure because When I download the file.iso some files in the folder are damaged.
so I can not continue the instructions in the tutorial.
In the laptop where the download file.iso use the version of Ubuntu 11.10, while the netbook where I want to install the usb drive turtlebot i use the 10.04 version of ubuntu.
The netbook that i found in the Turtlebot is Asus Eee Pc Seashell series 1215N.
i'm sorry if my English is not very good, but I am an Italian student and I do not know how to speak well.

Best wishes
Roberta

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32263/turtlebot--2012-01.10.iso-problem-with-istallation-use-usb-drive-in-the-netbook-of-turtlebot-robot/) by [Roberta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2063/roberta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We were having the similar problems using the turtlebot-2012-01-10.iso. We tried to create a bootable USB using the Startup Disk Creator program in Ubuntu 11.10, however it never worked, which may be due to the following bug:

"It is not possible to create Ubuntu 10.04 USB disks from the Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 10.10 due to a backwards incompatibility in the syslinux program."

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat/ReleaseNotes#Common%20Desktop%20Applications

So we ended up installing Ubuntu 10.04 from which we created a bootable USB (using the Startup Disk Creator) using the turtlebot-amd64.iso from:

http://pr.willowgarage.com/downloads/turtlebot/turtlebot-amd64.iso

---

Originally posted by [bootsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2218/bootsman/) with karma: 36 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2